# Setting Django WSGI workers with long external API response

Tags: python, django, django-views, wsgi, web-worker

I'm writing an e-commerce plug-in app in Python/Django that integrates with Shopify stores. Whenever a customer for a store reaches checkout, Shopify sends a request to my app with shopping cart and destination address data, and my app is required to respond with shipping price information. The problem is that I need to make an external API call between them sending me the request and sending them the response, and under moderate load, my WSGI workers get filled very easily.

I'm trying to avoid scaling out unnecessarily. Should I simply increase my number of workers past the recommended `cores * 2 + 1`? Do I simply monitor CPU load in order to adjust this number? What's the ideal CPU load % I should be looking for? Since I'm also handing short non-blocked requests from the same app, will this cause any problems?

Is Django simply not a good match for this kind of use-case? If so, what is a good match, and what would be the best way to apply it without rewriting my whole app?

EDIT: My WSGI server is Gunicorn

Comment: What kind of "workers" are you using? What wsgi server is this?

Comment: Gunicorn, updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do to improve the performance of gunicorn here. Given your design, it's almost certain that your workers are IO-bound. So for a start you could configure them to use multiple threads per worker; the docs suggest 2-4.

However, again because of the IO-bound nature of your site, it seems likely that you'll get even better improvements by using one of the asynchronous worker types. See [the design docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#async-workers) for details: I don't think there is much to choose between gevent and eventlet, personally I've had good results from the former.

Comment: Just be aware that using gevent or eventlet can create even worse situation if you don't understand how they work. Things will not magically improve things by simply switching. You need to ensure that you use no modules that would block and which aren't being patched by gevent or eventlet so they will work okay. Have anything which blocks and isn't greenlet aware and your whole process will hang and loose all concurrency benefits. Always safer to use multithreading.